# Metal Game project not working on OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: osx-elcapitan, metal, xcode7.1

I have installed the latest OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) with Xcode 7.1, and created a simple Mac Metal Game project. The program does not render an animated cube, but instead writes "Metal is not supported on this device" to the log, due to the MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(); returning nil.  The iOS & AppleTV version of the Metal Game template works fine. Has anyone else has similar issues?

Thanks,

Steve Sheets

Comment: If you are using OS X 10.11 then it might be an issue with your device. What Mac vintage are you using? The GPU's in some older Macs do not support Metal.

Comment: That is exactly the issue. I have a 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro from 2011, with an Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB. I would have thought there was enough power for Metal.  According to MacObserver, here are the unofficial requirements: Nvidia GeForce GTX 400 series and newer, Intel HD4000 and newer (Ivy Bridge or newer) or AMD HD7000 and newer.

Comment: Same Issue: MBP 2014 Nvidia 750M/Iris Pro